# Grant to user Permission on a specific Group

Tags: 2010

It's all in the Title,
I created a Group and i want to give a user permession to add other users to this group but he must only manage that group and nothing else.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make that particular user the OWNER of that group and also in group settings make sure that only Owner (but NOT members) could add members to the group.

Also make sure that the respective person has the appropriate Permissions on the site, to change security settings